# Warum gibt es zwei Präpositionen in "darf ich mit zu ihnen setzen"

Tags: preposition

Ich verstehe, dass manchmal eine der Präpositionen zu dem Verb gehört.

> Die Kinder rennen auf das Meer zu

Was ist der Grund hier:

> darf ich mit zu ihnen setzen

Comment: Das sieht ganz nach einem Vertipp-Fehler aus. Korrekt wäre "Darf ich **mich** zu Ihnen setzen?".

Comment: Wenn du _»ihnen«_ statt _»Ihnen«_ schreibst, sprichst du von mehreren Personen. Ist das beabsichtigt?

Comment: @pollitzsr ich weiß nicht. Es war ein audio.

Comment: @user5389726598465: Dann gehe ich davon aus, dass das _»mich«_ so schlecht gesprochen war, dass du _»mit«_ verstanden hast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tatsächlich ist es wahrscheinlich, dass der Satz ursprünglich `Darf ich *mich* zu ihnen setzen` heißen sollte. Aber auch in der Form ist er -zumindest umgangssprachlich- gebräuchlich.

`Darf ich mit` ist eine häufig benutzte Phrase um auszudrücken, dass man irgendwo mitgehen / irgendetwas mitmachen will, wo der andere hingeht / was der andere macht.

Beispiel: Person 1: Ich gehe ins Kino.
Person 2: Darf ich mit?
Oder ausführlicher: Darf ich mit ins Kino?

Ist der Ort ein anderer, ändert sich die Präposition:
P1: Ich gehe zu mir nach Hause.
P2: Darf ich mit zu Dir nach Hause?

In diesem Sinne ist auch der genannte Satz zu sehen:
P1: ich setze mich hin
P2: darf ich mit zu Dir setzen?

ALT: Klingt etwas holprig, ist aber durchaus gebräuchlich.

KORREKTUR: Ich war hier etwas schlampig. Tatsächlich meinte ich mit "gebräuchlich" den Satz: Darf ich mit zu Dir **sitzen**. Das Verb **setzen** würde tatsächlich ein "mich" vor dem "mit" voraussetzen und ist damit falsch. Danke an alle Kommentargeber.

Comment: Bei "Darf ich mit zu dir setzen" fehlt aber auf jeden Fall noch ein "mich". Sonst würde das Akkusativobjekt fehlen, da "setzen" transitiv ist.

Comment: Hast recht... nur wenn das Verb sitzen hiesse, könnte man das mich weglassen

Comment: Der 'etwas holprige' Satz _darf ich mit zu Dir setzen?_ ist für meine Begriffe in jedem deutschen Dialekt, Soziolekt und in allen Stilebenen inakzeptabel - allenfalls ginge _darf ich mit bei Dir sitzen?_ War das ein Tippfehler?

Comment: Hingegen wäre *Darf ich mit Ihnen schlafen* in vielen deutschen Soziolekten und Dialekten ein wohlgeformter und akzeptabler Satz.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Wenn das jemand zu mir sagen würde fände ich den Satz nicht akzeptabel. Ich vermute du meinst grammatikalisch?

Answer (score 4):

Ich vermute, der Satz sollte heißen, *Darf ich mich mit zu Ihnen setzen?*

Der Infinitiv der Ausgangs-Verbgruppe wäre *sich zu jemandem setzen*, erweitert zu *'sich mit zu jemandem setzen'*.

Ob das 'mit' dann Präposition oder abgetrenntes Verbpräfix oder vielleicht eher Adverb ist, wurde für ein ähnliches Beispiel kürzlich diskutiert [*kommst du nicht mit Kaffee trinken?*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43652/position-of-the-separable-prefix/43839#43839). Um es abzukürzen, würde ich das 'mit' hier als Adverb mit der Bedeutung '(ihr sitzt da zwar schon zu mehreren, aber ich würde aus welchem Grund auch immer gerne) *mit an eurem Tisch* (sitzen)'. 'Mit' kann im Deutschen ziemlich flexibel benutzt werden und ist oft nicht klar einzuordnen.

Ein ähnliches Beispiel wäre '*Kann ich nicht mit auf die Party gehen, die anderen aus meiner Klasse dürfen doch auch alle!*' Auch hier ist mit eine Abkürzung für das Modaladverbial (eher: Sozialadverbial) 'mit den anderen zusammen' und trägt alleinstehend die adverbiale Funktion.

In dem angefragten Satz fasse ich das 'mit' teilweise auch lokal auf, aber es ist auch hier ein 'soziales mit'. Es lässt sich soweit ich sehe in der Konstruktion 'mit zu Ihnen setzen' nicht zu einem richtigen Adverbial expandieren, weil 'zu Ihnen' quasi dasselbe bedeutet wie 'mit'. Dieselbe Bedeutung ist hier sowieso schon zweimal ausgedrückt. Eine Alternative wäre 'kann ich mich mit an Ihren Tisch setzen?' Man könnte es auch verdreifachen: 'kann ich mich mit zu Ihnen an Ihren Tisch setzen?'

Möglicherweise geht es nicht nur um den letzten freien Platz in einem Restaurant, sondern um eine Suche nach Anschluss in dieser Situation, also um ein 'ich möchte hier nicht gerne allein sitzen'. Das lässt sich nicht klar erkennen. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich in einer solchen Situation nicht eher fragen würde 'kann ich mich zu Ihnen setzen?', ohne 'mit'. Jedenfalls bedeutet das 'mit': 'es sitzen doch auch schon andere (oder jemand anderes) mit da.'