# "Willst du mit zu mir kommen?"

Tags: verb, preposition

I don't understand what the preposition "mit" usage in the example above.
If I was writing the sentence, I'd simply omit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb is *[mitkommen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitkommen),* and it is spilt in two parts. Therefore *mit-* is not a preposition but a prefix wandering about. An alternative way to phrase this would be *“Willst du zu mir mitkommen?”*

> [mitkommen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/deutsch-englisch/mitkommen)
>   verb [ intransitive ] [ trennbar, unreg., Perfekt mit sein ] /ˈmɪtkɔmən/
>   ​
>   andere an einen bestimmten Ort begleiten
>   to come (along/too)
>   Wir gehen Eisessen, kommst du mit?
>   We’re going for some ice cream. Do you want to come?
>   Synonym → mitgehen

That means, as is someone asks another person to join in on the way.

Leaving out *mit*:

> “Willst du zu mir kommen?”

Would be used if the person *mir* is already at the destination (or not, in fact) and the person called *du* travels alone.

*Mitkommen* is more like 'escort', 'accompany' or 'come along' than just 'come' (alone, by yourself, ).

From comment by Janka:

> In your example, *mitkommen* is used as an infinitive to the modal verb *wollen*. The prefix is usually not split from the infinitive, and *Willst du zu mir mitkommen?* is in fact as valid as your example. The prefix *mit-* however is special in some regards. It's also one of those few prefixes you could put on an already prefixed verb, e.g. *mitansehen*.

Comment: I always knew that the prefix should always be at the end , Is mitkommen an exception or could we do this with other verbs too ( putting prefix in the middle of the sentence )

Comment: @YomnaEssam Change always to usually: Ich spreche dem Verb *mitkommen* [ab](https://www.verbformen.com/conjugation/absprechen.htm), eine absolute Ausnahmeregel zu repräsentieren. Aber das sprechen wir lieber ab nach dem nächsten Sonnenaufgang. Manchmal verhandelt man sowas lieber [nach](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachverhandeln) bei Sonnenschein?

Comment: @Yomna Essam: In your example, *mitkommen* is used as an infinitive to the modal verb *wollen*. The prefix is usually **not split** from the infinitive, and *Willst du zu mir mitkommen?* is in fact as valid as your example. The prefix mit- however is special in some regards. It's also one of those few prefixes you could put on an already prefixed verb, e.g. *mitansehen*.

Comment: @Janka I would understand *mit* in this example to be an adverb and the main verb to be *kommen*. A similar dispute arised [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43652/position-of-the-separable-prefix). Could you please provide a link to any formal source of grammar or a quote from a textbook that supports the idea of *wandering prefixes* in the middle of the sentence?

Comment: These aren't "wandering prefixes". In contrary, the adverb+verb combination *mit+kommen* means *exactly* the same as the verb *mitkommen* and in no way some sort of *kommen*. E.g. *Möchtest du mit mir (mit)kommen. — Er kommt mit mir (mit).* This additional *mit* doesn't even intensify the action.

Comment: @Janka Thank you, I totally agree with that. This clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely convinced, that this is an example of *mitkommen*, so my attempt here:

If one is already at home, he could suggest:

> Willst Du zu mir kommen?

The mentioned sentence is typically used, if the subject is not at home but still has to go there and suggests that the addressed person joins him.

So a more exact translation would be:

> Would you join me going home?

Another scenario, where *mit* is applicable is, if another person was asked before and already agreed, so *mit* means to join that different person instead of the speaker.

Comment: How would that "at home" scenario lead to using *mit*, like in the OP example?

Comment: @LangLangC: you seem to refer to a context I can't recognize from the terse original question. Which? (With *mentioned sentence* I intended to refer to the OP example...)

Comment: That's the point. For your example to match the OP a context needs to be elaborated. Sth like: Alice is at home and refers to someone else (Bob) who already agreed to come over. Now she asks Bob's roommate Clint if he wants to join Bob in coming over? (Mit Bob kommen, mit Bob mitkommen.)